# Error compiling template:Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

Hei, make a vue app.
When running it shows up part of the app, the add event don´t show up and not even show the data. 
Before it show the same error but different area, and i could fixed it but now i can´t figure it out. I´ve been searching here and on the net, but nothing so far. I know it was so be something with the template in html, but can´t figure it out. First time working with Vue.
Thank you. Here the error

```
<div class="container" id="events">
     <!-- add an event form -->
     <div class="col-sm-6">
       <div class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3>Add an Event</h3>    
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">

            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Event Name" v-model="event.name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Event Description" v-model="event.description"></textarea>
            </div>  
            <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Date" v-model="event.date">
            </div>

            <button class="btn btn-primary" v-on="click: addEvent">Submit</button>
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     </div>

- invalid expression: Unexpected token : in

    click: addEvent

  Raw expression: v-on="click: addEvent"



(found in <Root>)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to an incorrect *v-on* expression.

The **v-on** expression should look similar to the following:

```
v-on:click="addEvent"
```

Where *addEvent* is the name of the function to be called when the component is clicked.  For related examples see [Vue.js Event Handling](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html).

Comment: sorry, I was out. Yes it did. Thank you for your time and help